# Changing MetroFramework MetroMessageBox color

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, messagebox

I'm using [MetroFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroFramework/) on windows forms. I can't seem to change the MetroMessageBox's color. I am able to change the color if I use MessageBoxIcon on the parameter but it is limited to two colors, red for error and orange for warning. I tried changing the style of the main form but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way to change the color of the *MetroFramework*'s `MessageBox`. You could create your own `MessageBox` or you could just use the **5** built-in colors.

- Green: `MessageBoxIcon.Question`
- Blue: `MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk`,  `MessageBoxIcon.Information`
- Red: `MessageBoxIcon.Error`,  `MessageBoxIcon.Hand`,  `MessageBoxIcon.Stop`
- Orange: `MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation`,  `MessageBoxIcon.Warning`
- Gray:  `MessageBoxIcon.None`